# I want convert 'content://0@media/external/file/147' to file:///storage/sdcard0/files/X.pdf` in android?

Tags: java, android

```
Uri fileUri = getIntent().getData();
        if (!fileUri.getPath().contains("external") && fileUri.getScheme().equals("content")) {
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(fileUri, null, null, null, null);
            try {
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    fileName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                }
            } finally {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }if (!fileUri.getPath().contains("external") && fileUri.getScheme().equals("file")) {
            List<String> pathSegments = fileUri.getPathSegments();
            if (pathSegments.size() > 0) {
                fileName = pathSegments.get(pathSegments.size() - 1);
            }
        }
```